# How to change sp_send_dbmail queried attachment encoding?

Tags: sql, email, encoding, sp-send-dbmail

I use `sp_send_dbmail` to generate and send files that are fed to other program. The program digests "ANSI/ASCII" and "ISO-8859-1" encoding. But I can't get `sp_send_dbmail` to make one.

Procedure call looks like this

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name= @profile_name, 
    @recipients  = @recipients,
    @body = @body,
    @subject = @subject,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1, 
    @query_result_header = 0,
    @query_result_no_padding = 1,
    @query = @query,
    @query_attachment_filename = @fname,
    @query_result_width = 4000,
    @mailitem_id = @mailitem_id OUTPUT
```

So the attachment is created from results of passed query. But the resulting file that is actually attached to mail for some reason is encoded with UCS2 Little Endian. 
Is there a way to change it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sp\_send\_dbmail executed from job fails with query result attached as file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112849/sp-send-dbmail-executed-from-job-fails-with-query-result-attached-as-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found workaround that allow to switch between UTF/ANSI. 
In order to do that you need to modify `sp_send_dbmail` like that:

1. Add new parameter to procedure somemthing like `@ANSI_Attachment BIT = 0`
2. Replace piece of its code `IF(@AttachmentsExist = 1) BEGIN ....... END`
   with

`IF (@AttachmentsExist = 1)

```
BEGIN
    if (@ANSI_Attachment = 1) 
    begin
        --Copy temp attachments to sysmail_attachments      
        INSERT INTO sysmail_attachments(mailitem_id, filename, filesize, attachment)
        SELECT @mailitem_id, filename, filesize, 
                convert(varbinary(max), 
                    substring( -- remove BOM mark from unicode
                        convert(varchar(max), CONVERT (nvarchar(max), attachment)), 
                        2, DATALENGTH(attachment)/2
                    )
                )
        FROM sysmail_attachments_transfer
        WHERE uid = @temp_table_uid
    end else begin
        --Copy temp attachments to sysmail_attachments      
        INSERT INTO sysmail_attachments(mailitem_id, filename, filesize, attachment)
        SELECT @mailitem_id, filename, filesize, attachment
        FROM sysmail_attachments_transfer
        WHERE uid = @temp_table_uid
    end
END `
```

This does the same but if in procedure call @ANSI_Attachment = 1 is used it removes unicode BOM mark before sending.

Peeked that solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703/sp-send-dbmail-attachment-encoding)